# Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller <UINavigationController: 0xb359a20> while a presentation or dismiss is in progress

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller, poptoviewcontroller

In my Application what i'm doing is:

rootViewController -> pushViewController -> pushViewController -> pushViewController -> presentModalViewController

From presentModalViewController i want to go to rootViewController Directly.

So what i did is :

```
while(theViewController = [theObjectEnumerator nextObject ])
     {
         if([theViewController modalTransitionStyle] == UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical)
         {
             [self.mNavigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:
              YES];
         }
     }
 }else
while(theViewController = [theObjectEnumerator nextObject ])
{
    if([theViewController modalTransitionStyle] == UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical)
    {
        [self.mNavigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

but here i'm getting a message

**Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller  while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!**

and after this app crashes.

I searched about this but couldn't find anything useful for me,
Can any body explain why this is happening?

Comment: Well, from the way your error says, it seems that you are trying pop from the view controller at the same time that the view is modally transitioning..

Comment: Maybe you can present the modal view right from the `navigationViewController`.

Comment: Or, if you are okay with it. `popToRoot` at the dismiss completion block.

Comment: i can't use popToRootViewController as the current view is presentmodalviewcontroller,so i guess i have to do like dismissPresentmodalviewcontroller -> popToRootViewController.@kyle

Comment: i have edited the code,still it's not working @kyle

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [(UINavigationController *)self.presentingViewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}];
```

This code work fine for me,

**Important**:

the `viewController` must be presented by the `navigationController`. (In most cases)
If not, call `self.presentingViewController.navigationController`.

Comment: This is correct method for nested dismiss and presentation. thanks!

Comment: I get the 'Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for' warning when using this method